# Sql pivot for report

Tags: sql, sql-server

hello I have been stuck here for a week...
say I have this result in my query..

```
Branch   Pay1   Pay2   Pay3   Pay4
Branch1  100    100    100    100
Branch1  150    150    150    150
Branch2  200    200    200    200
Branch3  200    200    200    200
```

I want to make something like this

```
Branch   Pay1   Pay2   Pay3   Pay4
Branch1  250    250    250    250
Branch2  200    200    200    200
Branch3  200    200    200    200
```

And the the final result is like this

```
Item   Branch1   Branch2   Branch3   
pay1   250       200       200
pay2   250       200       200   
pay3   250       200       200    
pay4   250       200       200
```

hope you can help me to do this..thanks a lot..

by the way this is my query..for the first result

```
Select distinct 
    --pr_employees.Fullname as Name
   --,
   PR_Employees.BranchID,PR_payroll.BasicPay as [BasicPay]
   ,PR_Empearnings.EarningAmt
   ,PR_Earnings.Description
   ,pr_payroll.Overtime
   ,pr_payroll.Period
   ,Pr_payroll.SundayOT as [Sunday OT]
   ,Pr_Payroll.PaidHol as [Paid Hol]
   ,pr_payroll.ThirteenthMonthPay as [Thirteen MO]
   ,pr_payroll.Grosspay as [Gross Amount]
   ,pr_payroll.WithHoldingTax as [WithTax]
   ,pr_payroll.SSSPremium as [SSS Cont]
   ,pr_payroll.SSSLoan as [SSS Loan]
   ,pr_payroll.PagibigPremium as [Pagibig Cont]
   ,pr_payroll.PagibigLoan as [Pagibig Loan]
   ,pr_payroll.NHIPPremium as Medicare
   ,pr_payroll.TotalDeductions as [Total Ded]
   ,pr_Payroll.netpay as [Net with OD]
   ,pr_payroll.netnoOd as [Net no OD]
   ,prchargesAdvances.Credit
   ,prchargesadvancesTypes.ChargesTypeName
 from pr_employees
  left join pr_payroll on PR_Employees.EmpID=PR_Payroll.EmpID
  left join PR_EmpEarnings on PR_Payroll.EmpID=PR_EmpEarnings.EmpID
  left join PR_Earnings on PR_EmpEarnings.EarningId=pr_earnings.earningid
  left join PR_Overtime on PR_Overtime.EmpID=PR_Payroll.EmpID
  left join PRChargesAdvances on PRChargesAdvances.transactiondate=pr_payroll.period   
   and prchargesadvances.empid=pr_payroll.empid
  left join PRChargesAdvancesTypes on PRChargesAdvances.ChargeTypeID=PRChargesAdvancesTypes.ChargesTypeID
 where PR_Payroll.Period='8/31/2013'
```

Comment: What query did you run to get that result? (please paste the sql)

Comment: I have posted my query.. but that is just for the first result

Comment: How many branch IDs exist? Would it be acceptable if all of them had to be specified in the query?

Comment: there only 6 branchid but when i tried my query it return 7, which is there is one id that duplicates

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  2005 and above has some great pivot functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a template than a solution, but I'll explain.

In the with clause below, you are establishing the aggregates by branch. This would give you the first step towards your desired output (the first desired result set in your post), if you ran it independently as its own query (renaming and adding all of your pay columns).

You then run several queries connected by unions, where you specify as a literal the pay column for which you'll be summing (you have to type it in as a literal, which is why I used the word 'literal' to illustrate each time. You then sum up, one row per pay field, and column per branch (via a case statement), the aggregates from the query in the with clause. The only reason I'm using a sum of the case statement is so that you get all #s on the same row for each pay field.

You have more than 4 pay columns (as you know) so you'll have to add several more unions until you're done (and rename all of the pay columns and the branch IDs to whatever they are).

```
with sub as
 (select branch,
         sum(pay1) as sum_py1 sum(pay2) as sum_py2 sum(pay3) as sum_py3 sum(pay4) as sum_py4
    from bunchoftbls
   where PR_Payroll.Period = '8/31/2013'
   group by branch)
select 'Pay1 literal'
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch1' then sum_py1 else 0 end) as branch1
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch2' then sum_py1 else 0 end) as branch2
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch3' then sum_py1 else 0 end) as branch3
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch4' then sum_py1 else 0 end) as branch4
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch5' then sum_py1 else 0 end) as branch5
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch6' then sum_py1 else 0 end) as branch6
from sub
union all
select 'Pay2 literal'
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch1' then sum_py2 else 0 end) as branch1
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch2' then sum_py2 else 0 end) as branch2
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch3' then sum_py2 else 0 end) as branch3
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch4' then sum_py2 else 0 end) as branch4
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch5' then sum_py2 else 0 end) as branch5
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch6' then sum_py2 else 0 end) as branch6
from sub
union all
select 'Pay3 literal'
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch1' then sum_py3 else 0 end) as branch1
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch2' then sum_py3 else 0 end) as branch2
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch3' then sum_py3 else 0 end) as branch3
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch4' then sum_py3 else 0 end) as branch4
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch5' then sum_py3 else 0 end) as branch5
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch6' then sum_py3 else 0 end) as branch6
from sub
union all
select 'Pay4 literal'
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch1' then sum_py4 else 0 end) as branch1
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch2' then sum_py4 else 0 end) as branch2
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch3' then sum_py4 else 0 end) as branch3
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch4' then sum_py4 else 0 end) as branch4
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch5' then sum_py4 else 0 end) as branch5
        , sum(case when branch = 'Branch6' then sum_py4 else 0 end) as branch6
from sub
```